# TeamCity Trigger on Pull Request vs Trigger on Merge

Tags: git, github, teamcity

We build features in GitHub branches (one feature branch to one feature). We have a develop branch and a master branch. Both should always be green.

We use TeamCity for builds and deploys. What I want to get to is  that when a pull request is created (from the feature branch to develop), TeamCity automatically builds and tests the request, then boots up an EC2 instance so that it can be manually tested. When the pull request is then merged, TeamCity builds, tests and creates a docker image which we push out onto ECS.

This all works, except we have the triggering wrong.

1) For building the pull request, the VCS root has a default branch set as `develop` and has a branch specification of `+:refs/pull/(*/merge)` - we don't want to solely build the pull request but build the merged code. We then deploy this out onto an EC2 instance for manual testing.

2) TeamCity reports the status of building the pull request to GitHub and, after manual testing using the EC2 instance, the code is merged from the feature branch into develop. At this point, we want to build the code in develop and then we push out the new micro-service onto the Amazon ECS. For building once the pull request is merged into develop, the VCS root has a default branch set as `develop`.

In reality, 1 is always triggered e.g. for both raising a pull request and the merge into develop. 2 is triggered only when the merge into develop occurs which is correct.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

I've clarified the two build configurations we use above

Comment: The way you've described this makes it sounds like there are two VCS roots, or you are trying to dynamically set the default branch (might be the way I've interpreted it) Can you confirm that you only have one VCS root and you're not changing the default / branch specs dynamically.

Comment: We do have two VCS roots for the project, one VCS root for each of the build configurations. We aren't changing the default or branch specs dynamically, its just that we have set the two VCS roots differently.

Comment: Aha - I would question the need for two VCS roots as this should work off of the one - Did you want to chat about this? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117201/evolve-software-ltd

Comment: Indeed, no need for two VCS roots pointing to the same repository.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, if you only want to only build the merged code of your pull request, you don't need to specify the parenthesis.

https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2013/02/automatically-building-pull-requests-from-github-with-teamcity/

> Now, (...) see whether the particular request was the result of a merge or just the branch itself. For that, we can specify the following in the Branch Specification
>
> +:refs/pull/(*/merge)

Once the pull request created, TeamCity will only test the result of the merged code into develop.

Using the TeamCity `automatic merge` feature (included in TC9), a new commit will be triggered on the `develop` branch, which will run your configuration (build on develop, tests on develop, deploy...) properly

So, you might just have to replace your branch specification from: `+:refs/pull/(*/merge)` to `+:refs/pull/*/merge`

Comment: I have done this - I now have a single VCS root monitoring develop and then in the branch specification I have +:refs/pull/*/merge. This obviously triggers both build configurations so I have tried adding a branch filter to the trigger with +:refs/pull/*/merge - but this then prevents it being triggered on a new pull request. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple. It is github who is causing this problem.
The `+:refs/pull/*/merge` branch is updated every time github thinks there's a change and "rebuilds" the merge result and teamcity triggers fire everytime.

Sometimes this just happens when someone reads and comments the open pull request. It is definetively happening at first when opening the PR (as wanted) and second when the actual merge occurs and the result is rebuild. There is no way around that at the moment. Github webhooks should inform about the status of the PR (got opened/ closed and completed) and TC trigger rules should do the rest... Maybe in future!

BTW, I have separate VCS for every build config. Works fine and makes it more flexible...

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Evolve Software Ltd that you can likely address all build configuration needs with a single VCS root.  I do not get exactly what is wrong with scenario 1 but it is implied that you do not want to build the merges to develop there.
I think you are looking for appropriate specification of Branch Filter in your VCS Trigger for the relevant build configurations.  Syntax is fairly simple and TC docs cover this part if I am unclear:

- `+:<default>` will include the default branch (as specified in vcs root)
- `-:<default>` will exclude the default branch
- `+ or -:branch_name` will include or exclude the logical branch name as specified in branch specification (the part in parens or the entire thing if no parens)

Note that if you specify an 'exclude' entry you need to specify an 'include' entry, as well, even if just +:* and you can specify as many entries as needed (on different lines).

Hope this helps.